# How to multiple non-breaking spaces in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How to have have four or five consecutive non-breaking spaces in HTML using jsx and React. I try

```
`asdf${'      '}`
```

but it only renders one space. How do I do this in React?

Comment: Have you tried multiple `&nbsp` ?

Comment: Most likely you should use CSS instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can use CSS white-space property for it

```
<div style = {{ whiteSpace: "pre" }}>{`asdf${'      '}`}</div>
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-breaking space html entity inside render

```
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-breaking space as shown below,

```js
{`asdf${'      '}`}
```